# Admin site of my Django project doesn't work

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I'm new to Django and I'm following the tutorial of activating the admin site. I did the following configuration from the tutorial:

- Firstly, I uncommented the line `django.contrib.admin` in the apps part of settings.py.
- Then I executed the command `python manage.py syncdb` in a terminal.
- Then I uncommented the lines `from django.contrib import admin`, `admin.autodiscover()`, and `url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls))` in urls.py; the resulting code is:

  ```
  from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url

  # Uncomment the next two lines to enable the admin:
  from django.contrib import admin
  admin.autodiscover()

  urlpatterns = patterns('',
  # Examples:
  # url(r'^$', 'mysite.views.home', name='home'),
  # url(r'^mysite/', include('mysite.foo.urls')),

  # Uncomment the admin/doc line below to enable admin documentation:
  # url(r'^admin/doc/', include('django.contrib.admindocs.urls')),

  # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
  url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
  )
  ```

And when I run the project I get the following error:

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/

Using the URLconf defined in mysite.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

^admin/

The current URL, , didn't match any of these.

You're seeing this error because you have DEBUG = True in your Django settings file. Change that to False, and Django will display a standard 404 page.
```

What can I do?

---

Thank you for your answer, but when I try to access `http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin` I get the following error:

```
DoesNotExist at /admin/

Site matching query does not exist. Lookup parameters were {'pk': 1}

Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/
Django Version:     1.5
Exception Type:     DoesNotExist
Exception Value:    

Site matching query does not exist. Lookup parameters were {'pk': 1}

Exception Location:     /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py in get, line 401
Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python
Python Version:     2.7.3
Python Path:    

['/home/eren/mysite',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PIL',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gst-0.10',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0',
 '/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntu-sso-client']

Server time:    Fri, 24 May 2013 23:29:03 +0300
```

Comment: from the urls.py, there'll be no matching for `^$`, thus you'll get 404. you'll need `/admin/` to access the admin part.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but when I try access to http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin I have a error like you can see above where I edited de question.

Comment: @yuwang means you need to visit 127.0.0.1:8000/admin/ - note the trailing slash - instead of 127.0.0.1/admin, without the trailing slash; they are not the same unless you make them so.

Comment: Another thing is you might need to `syncdb`.

Answer (score 2):

You should access admin site at `http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin` not `http://127.0.0.1:8000/`.

Note: the `admin` suffix.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but when I try access to http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin I have a error like you can see above where I edited de question.